# Un input submit no ejecuta codigo PHP y JavaScript a la vez

Tags: php, javascript

**Resumen del problema**

Buenas a todos. Mi problema es que tengo un formulario y tengo mi codigo en php que guarda los datos de este formulario en una base de datos cuando pulso el input submit, ademas tengo mi codigo en javascript (con jquery) que detecta este evento submit del formulario y ejecuta su función (crea una fila en una tabla de la pagina).

**Ambos funcionan correctamente**, pero mi archivo php unicamente funciona si elimino la etiqueta `<script>` que linkea a mi codigo JavaScript, de lo contrario (si dejo la etiqueta) actua como si no existiese el archivo PHP. Al eliminar esa etiqueta `<script>` se guarda exitosamente los datos del formulario en la base de datos.

Lo que yo quiero es que ambos funcionen, o sea que al pulsar el input submit se guarde los datos en la base de datos y que se cree la fila en la tabla de mi pagina con mi codigo en JavaScript.

**Lo que he intentado**

He buscado mi pregunta en internet pero parece que no la formule bien pues no encuentro una respuesta exactamente a mi pregunta. He pensado que quiza se pueda hacer con AJAX pero yo no se AJAX asi que no he intentado eso. Asi que primero queria preguntar en esta comunidad si quiza haya una solucion mas sencilla.

**Codigo**

Mi formulario:

```
<form action="guardartarea.php" method = "POST" id="formGuardarTarea">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" maxlength="128" minlength="4" id="inTitulo" name="titulo" class=" form-control" placeholder=" T&iacute;tulo" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="descripcion" maxlength="256" id="inDesc" rows="4"class="form-control" placeholder="Descripci&oacute;n" required></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" id="inFecha" name="fecha" class=" form-control" placeholder=" Fecha Limite">
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="btnGuardarTarea" name = "guardarTarea" value ="Guardar Tarea"> </form>
```

La parte del codigo JavaScript donde uso el evento submit de ese formulario: (Detecta el evento submit del formulario y luego verifica los inputs de este y ejecuta la funcion crearTarea, esta funcion lo que hace es modificar el DOM de la pagina añadiendo un tr en una tabla de la pagina)

```
$("#formGuardarTarea").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($("#inTitulo").val() !== "" && $("#inDesc").val() !== "") {

        if ($("#inFecha").val() !== "") {
            crearTarea(
                $("#inTitulo").val(),
                $("#inDesc").val(),
                $("#inFecha").val()
            );
        } else {
            crearTarea(
                $("#inTitulo").val(),
                $("#inDesc").val(),
                "Sin fecha límite"
            );
        }

    }

    $("#inTitulo").val("");
    $("#inDesc").val("");
    $("#inFecha").val("");

});
```

Codigo PHP donde se envia el formulario:

```
    <?php

include('conexion.php');

if (isset($_POST['guardarTarea'])) {
  try{
    $title = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['titulo']));
    $description = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['descripcion']));
    $date = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['fecha']));
    
    $query = "INSERT INTO `tareas` (`title`, `description`, `limit_date`) VALUES (:titulo, :descripcion, :fecha)";
    $resultadousuario = $conection->prepare($query);

    $resultadousuario->bindValue(":titulo", $title);
    $resultadousuario->bindValue(":descripcion", $description);
    $resultadousuario->bindValue(":fecha", $date);
    $resultadousuario->execute();
 

  }catch(Exception $ex){
    die("Error al conectar:  $e->getMessage()");
  }
        
} 

?>
```

*Muchas gracias de antemano, si necesitan algun dato más o algo no quedo claro me dicen y lo corrijo,*

Comment: Bienvenido! Es bueno que subas el código, al menos con 3 campos del formulario como como modelo y ver dónde tienes los <script> así si es un problema de sintaxis te podemos ayudar o buscar otra forma de hacerlo. Te esperamos!

Comment: Solo como aclaración: un botón en el navegador no puede ejecutar directamente código PHP, porque PHP se ejecuta en el servidor y tienes 2 opciones: 1) Ejecutar el formulario normalmente (recargando la página) 2) Usar AJAX para comunicar el navegador con el servidor. En cuanto a la pregunta, puedes mejorarla agregando solo piezas de código, no se necesita ver todo, solo un [ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ya agregue fotos de mi codigo.  Y no estoy haciendo que un boton en el navegador ejecute codigo php, estoy ejecutando ese codigo en PHP con el input type="submit" del formulario.